# Dynamically convert single rows to multiple rows based on attributes value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with sql query to dynamically convert single record to multiple based on attributes value

Data looks like below

```
A            B             C

0            100          10
```

Output should be , Column D is based on B/C which is 10 iterations. Number of iterations are not fixed, it can be any number , so output can be 3 rows, 10 rows, 100 or 1000 or 10000 based on value of B and C.

```
A   B   C   D

0   100  10  10
0   100  10  20
0   100  10  30
0   100  10  40
0   100  10  50
0   100  10  60
0   100  10  70
0   100  10  80
0   100  10  90
0   100  10  100
```

Please advise.

Comment: Google how to do running totals using Window Functions

Comment: How do you come up with 10? Is it just dividing B and C? And then the value in D = 1 * (B/C)? This is perfect time to use a tally table.

Comment: what about if Column B is 100 and C is 30 ? how many rows do you expect then ?

Comment: Column C decides the number of iterations so it will not be fraction. Basically we have to generate multiple rows based on this logic.

Comment: @M.Ali Well 3 of course, SQL Server says that 100/30 = 3 :D

Comment: I have provided an answer which returns desired output for the rows in your question but I am still a bit unsure about the values in Column D. How are they calculated.

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare @t table (A  INT, B INT, C INT);
INSERT INTO @t Values ( 0 , 100 , 10);

SELECT *
FROM @t t 
 CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP (t.B / t.c) 
                        t.c * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) D
                FROM master..spt_values x CROSS JOIN master..spt_values y
            ) c;
```

Comment: If you change 10 to 20, then your script will show 20 rows instead of 5 rows

Comment: @TonyDong apparently this is what is expected, read the comments of the OP, Column C defines the number of rows to be returned.

Comment: It say Column D is based on B/C which is 10 iterations

Comment: I am guessing that ColumnD is basically ROW_NUMBER * (B/C) but hard to say for sure. Of course that part should be simple once they understand how to use a tally table.

Comment: @SeanLange I think you are right but really OP should provide more information about their requirements, considering this is probably the first time this OP has asked a question on this forum, taking it a bit easy on him/her. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE`

```
WITH numbers AS 
    ( 
      SELECT a,b,c, C AS  Number  
      FROM Table1
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT a,b,c, Number + b/c 
      FROM Numbers  
      WHERE Number + b/c  <= b 
    )     
    SELECT * FROM numbers
```